# Why my MacVIM and terminal vi looks different?

Tags: vim, clojure, macvim

I'm using both console and GUI VIM. Cannot understand why my GUI vim shows different color palette and different parentheses colors (Rainbow parentheses plugin)

Console vim is in the left (and it seems to be better):

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Terminal vim only has (at most) 256 colors, gvim/macvim has a lot more (#000000 - #FFFFFF).

If you look in your colorscheme/plugins for highlight commands. Terminal vim will you ctermfg/ctermbg and gvim/macvim will use guifg/guibg when selecting which color to use.